# Why Full GC cannot free some memory but ForceGarbageCollection triggered by JVMTI can

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I have a spring boot service. and not set -Xmx , so when running after some days, memory will cost too much.

and I find Full gc cannnot free some memory， but if I trigger one force gc, more memory will be freed.

My Env is Java8 and -XX:+UseParallelGC

below is the java pid info :

```
 -XX:-BytecodeVerificationLocal
 -XX:-BytecodeVerificationRemote 
 -XX:CICompilerCount=4 
 -XX:InitialHeapSize=268435456
 -XX:+ManagementServer 
 -XX:MaxHeapSize=4280287232 
 -XX:MaxNewSize=1426587648 
 -XX:MinHeapDeltaBytes=524288 
 -XX:NewSize=89128960 
 -XX:OldSize=179306496 
 -XX:+UseParallelGC
```

Below gc log shows one Full GC.

- **Used Size from 0.38G down to 0.16G** <-- shoud be 0.08G, has 80M not free
- **total size from 0.51G up to 0.79G**

```
2019-11-04T13:50:28.210+0800: 166.279: [Full GC (Ergonomics) [PSYoungGen: 52708K->0K(296448K)] [ParOldGen: 195505K->151265K(497664K)] 248213K->151265K(794112K), [Metaspace: 70984K->70983K(1114112K)], 0.2154114 secs] [Times: user=1.75 sys=0.00, real=0.22 secs]
```

Below gc log shows one Force GC.

- **Used Size from 0.25G down to 0.08G** <--  this is reasonable
- **total size from 0.79G up to 0.85G**

```
2019-11-04T13:51:13.691+0800: 211.761: [GC (JvmtiEnv ForceGarbageCollection) 
Desired survivor size 93847552 bytes, new threshold 5 (max 15)
[PSYoungGen: 96393K->44887K(338432K)] 247659K->196152K(836096K), 0.0668965 secs] [Times: user=0.05 sys=0.01, real=0.07 secs] 
2019-11-04T13:51:13.759+0800: 211.828: [Full GC (JvmtiEnv ForceGarbageCollection) [PSYoungGen: 44887K->0K(338432K)] [ParOldGen: 151265K->78647K(509952K)] 196152K->78647K(848384K), [Metaspace: 70983K->70983K(1114112K)], 0.1138409 secs] [Times: user=0.66 sys=0.00, real=0.11 secs]
```

So at the beginning, I suspect my code has some memory leak, but if force gc can free the memory, I think memory leak does not exist.

**I just want to know why the full gc cannot free some memory, but force gc can.**

EDIT:
Now I have learned that full gc would not clear all unused objects.
So if not set max memory limit, more memory will be committed. 
When unused objects are too much, OutOfMemoryError will happen.

Comment: Because that is the way that it is implemented.   But that's not the question you should really be asking.  (You don't *need* to know *why* `System.gc()` is not giving a reliable answer.) What you should really be asking is how to 1) find reliable evidence that a memory leak exists, and 2) how to track down the leak.

Comment: So you mean if Full GC cannot free, there exists memory leak?  I have used JProfiler  to help analyze heap. But I cannot find big object.

Comment: No.  That's not what I mean.

Comment: @StephenC  sorry, I know I need means to track memory problem. So I am not sure  If my jvm settings problem. But I just find that  auto FuLL GC is diffrent from ForceGarbageCollection.  And the latter can free more memory. and after Force GC,  used memory is same with service startup.  So I think the key is understanding this two gc's diffrence.

Comment: Sorry, but I disagree.  If there is a real memory leak, then it won't matter if there is a difference between the two ways of triggering a GC.  If you have a memory leak, you need to find it and fix it.  My point is that you can't rely on `System.gc()` to tell you if there is a real memory leak.  So ... don't use it for that.   You are asking the wrong question.  (Or to put it another way, if you could find out why `System.gc()` behaves differently, it wouldn't help you find the memory leak.)

Comment: @StephenC  Thank you very much. I get your point somewhat.  I may have wrong understanding about gc. At the beginning, I think that full gc will clear all unused objects. But It's wrong.  Diffrent GC Algothrhms have diffrent results.  And will trade off between throughput and latency.  
But One point I am sure is that GC will not clear used object. So If the memory is the same with that after the Force GC. I think May be there does not exist memory leak.
I have reset jvm options, (-Xms800m
-Xmx800m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC) fixed memory. and now have run 2 hours and no problem.